How to configure relationships
Suppose we have a Book class which contains two accounts:
public class Book 
{
    public PassiveAccount PassiveAccount { get; set; }
    public ActiveAccount AcctiveAccount { get; set; }
}

public Account 
{
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}

public ActiveAccount : Account //marker interface
{
}

public PassiveAccount : Account
{
}

How to properly or (if it is possible) configure this type of relationship. Can EF Core understand what exactly account to load when loading the book. As I guess it must distinguish those accounts by a discriminator field.
I can't decide how to solve this design problem in such a context.

why do you want an relazionship simply add a column active boolean, so you have everything needed

Nevertheless, It must reference two accounts simultaniouslly

Why do you need those marker interfaces? Just use Account directly.

Also, I would recommend making the properties in Book nullable.

@DavidG Yeah I saw "marker interface" after I wrote that comment.

@DavidG, Just for distinguishing purposes in database. If I use base class then I need to specify explicit Foreign Keys for that model? I would to know, Can ef use explicit type to distinguish those accounts

It depends on how you expect the database to be storing this data. If you have a PassiveAccountId property in the Book table, then you don't need to worry about a discriminator.

Suppose you are going to have more types of accounts (deleted, banned, closed etc), I suggest you this:
public class Book {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public AccountStatus Status {get; set;}
}

public class AccountStatus {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

Here you extracted the account's status to its own table, which you can extend, and you can link an Account to a status.
Also, your book now has a collection of accounts, and you can place in it as many as you want.
Entity Framework is going to understand these classes and the relations between them.
